# jQuery trigger click on elements cycling

Tags: jquery, loops, triggers, click, cycle

I have elements in page:

```
<a class="element" onclick="do this"></a>
<a class="element" onclick="do this"></a>
<a class="element" onclick="do this"></a>
<a class="element" onclick="do this"></a>
```

i need to trigger the click on each one and delay some time between the triggered clicks.

```
//for each one .element
$('.element').delay(800).trigger('click');
```

then i need to repeat this cycle as infite cycle, BUT i need to `stop it when user click on a .element`

i tryed many things like $.each( loop trigger); but i can't understand how to cycle all to infinite and stop it when i sad :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might exist more elegant solution, but here are my two cents:

```
​$(function(){
    $("a").on("click", function(e, d){
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        if(d !== true) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    });

    $("a:first").addClass("active");
    var timer = setInterval(doClick, 800);

    function doClick() {
        var $n = $(".active").next();
        if ($n.length == 0) {
            $n = $(".active").siblings().first();
        }
        console.log($n.length);
        $n.trigger("click", [true]);
    }
});
​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HvpMM/)

Comment: i just use onclick="" so i just need to cycle the trigger method for each element i can't redeclare on('click')

Comment: i just need to trigger in an infinite loop the click on each .element then stop loop if user clicks on 1 .element

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
$(function(){
    var links = $('.element');

    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        links.each(function(index, value){
            var link = $(this);
            setTimeout(function(){
                link.trigger('click', "trigger");
            }, 100 + index * 50);
        });
    }, 800);

    links.click(function(e, isTrigger){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!isTrigger)
        {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c2G6q/1/

Comment: you do not loop it infitely! :) this could be great !

Comment: i just use html onclick="" can't redeclare it

Comment: no sorry i thought i was clear with my question ... :( i just need to trigger in an infinite loop the click on each .element then stop loop if user clicks on 1 .element

Comment: @Aaaaaaa Yes, fix this. `setInterval` executes every 800 ms and 'setTimeout' once.

Comment: but i asked for someone who helps me in fix that :/

Comment: @Aaaaaaa Or this example: http://jsfiddle.net/c2G6q/2/ after click on link trigger will stop.

Comment: well there on fiddle is working for me not :( could be  that i'm using var links = $('.home-present a') ??

Comment: @Aaaaaaa Open console and check your selector. This selector will select something with class `.home-present` and then find links in it (children).